# Split string using seperator?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, string, split

I have a string `hai-welcome`.

I need to split the above string using `-` separator:

```
mySstring = "hai-welcome"
```

Seperate as:

```
firstString  = "hai"
secondString = "welcome.
```

Can anyone tell me the proper way to do this?